# Elasticsearch: Unknown s3 repository

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to configure my dockerized elasticsearch:2.4 in order to it's able to snapshoting my indices.

First of all, I've installed `cloud-aws` plugin:

```
docker exec -it es plugin install cloud-aws
```

Then, I'm trying to set up my repository:

```
docker exec -it es curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3' -d '
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "es-backup-living",
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "access_key": "-----",
    "secret_key": "-----"
  }
}
'
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this message from elasticsearch:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "repository_exception",
      "reason" : "[s3] failed to create repository"
    } ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[s3] failed to create repository",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Unknown [repository] type [s3]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Once `cloud-aws` is installed I've tried to get the list of plugins:

```
#docker exec -it es curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v'
name component version type url
```

As you can see the list is empty.

After having restarted my dockerized elasticsearch, the list of plugins keeps empty.

```
#docker stop es && docker start es
#docker exec -it es curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v'
name component version type url
```

**EDIT**

I've added the plugin on dockerfile adding:

```
RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install --batch cloud-aws
```

Once it's installed I'm getting another message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "repository_verification_exception",
      "reason" : "[s3] path  is not accessible on master node"
    } ],
    "type" : "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason" : "[s3] path  is not accessible on master node",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "i_o_exception",
      "reason" : "Unable to upload object tests-9SGwQ4I-Tj6iLEr_fG5Qgw/master.dat-temp",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "amazon_s3_exception",
        "reason" : "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 90B3CC8F3BDFE716)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I've added an user on AWS granting it with this policy:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::snaps.example.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::snaps.example.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not tell what is your version.

Note that from 5.0, you must use `repository-s3` plugin instead.

After you ran:

```
docker exec -it es plugin install cloud-aws
```

Did you restart elasticsearch?

You need to restart it. Have a look at `GET _cat/plugins?v` as well.
Make sure it's installed on all nodes.

Comment: Thanks @dadoonet. I've edited the post. What do you mean about `restart elasticsearch`? => `docker stop es && docker start es`? I'm using elasticsearch:2.4 docker image.

Comment: I don't know how you actually restart elasticsearch in the context of docker but as long as you can't see anything in `_cat/plugins` it means that your plugin is either not installed or not loaded by elasticsearch. Check your logs.

Comment: I've installed plugin installing it on dockerfile. Nevertheless, Could you help me with the related other issue I've added on post?

Comment: All nodes must have access to the S3 repository. If you have more than one node running in your cluster check them all. I'd open a new thread as the initial question is solved IMO.